# Windows 10 Network Share - Different Permissions for Subfolders?

Tags: windows, permissions, network-shares

I have a Windows 10 Pro machine that I use as a home server for file sharing and streaming that is not on a domain. Network drives are formatted NTFS. I have a folder on the server called "DATA" that includes subfolders, including symlinks to other folders.

I want to give my kids access to the "DATA" folder primarily with read only for all files and subfolders, but a couple subfolders I want to give them write permission as well. I want all files read/write for DAD (me).

It seems share permissions are quite restrictive and inherited from the parent folder, even if I share a subfolder with different permissions, it will only give me those permissions if I access that share directly. (i.e. \server\data\public vs \server\data --> choose public).

As an example of the folder structure (read only means read only for kids):

```
DATA          --> read only (parent network share)
 - FILES      --> read/write anyone
 - GAME FILES --> read only (symlink)
 - LINUX ISO  --> read only
 - MOVIES     --> read only
 - MUSIC      --> read only
 - SOFTWARE   --> read only
 - TV SHOWS   --> read only
 - USERS      --> subfolder (symlink)
   - PUBLIC   --> read/write anyone
   - KID1     --> read/write only for KID1/DAD
   - KID2     --> read/write only for KID2/DAD
   - DAD      --> read/write only for DAD
```

I didn't want to go mucking about with NTFS permissions (folder properties -> security -> advanced) and risk screwing up access to files, but I'm assuming that may be my answer?

Or is there something else I'm missing entirely?

Thanks.

EDIT: I think I got it figured out.

For DATA folder, had to give full SHARE permission to everyone, but NTFS permissions allow only Read&Execute/List folder contents.

Then for KID1 folder for example, I disabled inheritance for NTFS permissions, and allowed them read and write privileges for that folder and subfolder. Now they can read the DATA folder items, but can't delete or create anything in there. But once they are in their "KID1" folder can create and delete folders on a whim.

But now my symlinks seem to be wonky. I'll have to figure that out next I guess.

Comment: I assume from your post that your children have their own computers.  Put the files for them in c:\family_data or like.  Now make user names on the main machine along with passwords. Set Properties, Sharing, Advanced sharing so that the user above has read/write access to the folder they should have and not anything else. This should work. It is the basis of how i set up generalized folder sharing between my machines.

Comment: To simplify things, Microsoft added a new sharing mechanism in.. "vista I think?".. They LOOK like one set of permissions but they are not.  Access to the share, and the NTFS ACLs (access control lists) are very different.  If you right click your folder at the root of the share and use "advanced sharing".. coupled with the Security tab on that folder and sub-folders you want to control access to... you will get what you want.  This confused MANY people so Microsoft added "simple sharing" as the default but it really isn't how things work under the hood.  Or @John answer is easy and good :)